# network issues after suspend on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: networking, 13.04

I've been having troubles with my wireless connections the past week im running Ubuntu 13.04 on an Acer aspire 4738z-4210 and a few days ago when i returned from suspend i got a enable network button unchecked and wouldn't turn on after i tried to click it I've tried finding my driver form my wireless and do a suspend driver but that hasnt affected it at all

Comment: I have similar issues when i update from ubuntu(64bit) 12.10 to 13.04.
maybe the next answer could help you resolve your issue. http://askubuntu.com/questions/287779/wired-network-is-not-stable-in-ubuntu-13-04-64-bit

Answer (score 0):

when this happens type this in terminal

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

it should fix things

I use this on ubuntu 13.10 because it has the same issue but I think it should work with 13.04 too